# rotating an Image with Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael, rotation

Im trying to create a button that will rotate my animation.
I have found some rotating scripts, but they wont work I cant find the problem.

Shouldn't this be enough ?

```
var angle = 90

function rotRect2()
{ 
rect2.animate({rotation: angle}, 1000, ">");
}
```

my animation name is rect2 and my button is calling the function rotRect2

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> var angle = 90 **;**

I think you forgot the ";" there or is it another problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at [this example](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html),
they're using the `{transform: "r" + angle}` form

I don't think there is a `rotation` attribute in the `rect` [SVG Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#RectElement)

Comment: I tried that one first but didnt work.. But I forgot the quote marks just like Joeri suggested.

It works with the transform attribute